# replace a word in a string if there is a given string using sed

Tags: string, sed

Consider the following strings:

```
function 12345 filename.pdf 6789 12
function 12345 filename.doc 7789 4567
```

Is there a way to search the strings using sed to see if they contain pdf or doc substrings, and replace the strings to the following?

```
function_pdf 12345 filename.pdf 6789 12
function_doc 12345 filename.doc 7789 4567
```

Comment: awk is good for this.

Comment: All the strings contain either .doc or .pdf.  Also the number of words in each string varies.

Comment: You want to drop the fourth column from the line whenever the third column ends with `.doc` or `.pdf` and you want to add `_doc` or `_pdf` to the first column?

Comment: My apologies. I have amended the strings to show that the number of words in each string is different.

Comment: add maybe also the info about ending double quote of each line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really have not specified the problem adequately, but perhaps you are looking for:

```
sed -e  '/\.pdf/s/function/function_pdf/g' -e /\.doc/s/function/function_doc/g'
```

Comment: You are missing a `'`. And as fedorqui has commented in my answer, `g` is not needed. Nice solution.

Comment: With `g` this is insufficiently careful as it may replace too much. Also the `\.pdf` (etc.) match is not sufficiently limited to possible match location.

Answer (score 1):

Using sed :

```
~$ cat i.txt
function 12345 filename.pdf 6789
function 12345 filename.doc 7789
function 12345 filename.txt 8888
~$ sed -e 's/\(function\) \(.*\)\(pdf\|doc\)\(.*\)/\1_\3 \2\3\4/' i.txt
function_pdf 12345 filename.pdf 6789
function_doc 12345 filename.doc 7789
function 12345 filename.txt 8888
```

Capture the extension with the regexp you want, then insert it where you want using `\x` notation.
From man sed:

> the special escapes \1 through \9 to refer to the corresponding matching sub-expressions in the regexp.

Comment: @fedorqui indeed. Bad habits…

Comment: @fredtantini all my strings end in a double quote ".  The sed command does everything as expected but drops the last double quote.

Comment: @Reza If your example input in the post doesn't match your reality you need to fix that.

Comment: @Reza Update your question. But I have edited my answer (by capturing the last part of the line).

Answer (score 1):

Through sed,

```
$ sed 's/^\([^[:space:]]\+\)\( [^[:space:]]\+ [^[:space:]]\+\.\)\(pdf\|doc\)/\1_\3\2\3/g' file
function_pdf 12345 filename.pdf 6789 12
function_doc 12345 filename.doc 7789 4567
```

Answer (score 0):

With awk:

```
awk '$1=="function" && ($3 ~ /\.(pdf|doc)$/) {$1=$1 "_" substr($3,length($3)-2)}7'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\( .*\.\)\([^ ]*\)\(.*\)/_\2&/' YourFile
```

the simpliest sed i found for this (sed seems very efficient for this)